# should i say the attached has 6 files or the attached have 6 files?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, grammatical-number

I have two question for the following sentence:

"the attached document has 6 files  ,if none of them suited what you are looking for let me know. "

Q1: should i say the attached has 6 files or the attached have 6 files ?
Q2: is it right to say "if none of them suited what you are looking for"?

Comment: I think this is just Too Basic, and therefore Off Topic, for ELU.

Answer (score 2):

The attached....has is correct, because it is a singular item. And it's fine to say the second line that if none suit, to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

"Has files" is correct. "The attached" is singular, not plural. It's irrelevant that the files are plural.

"If none of them **are** suited to what you are looking for..."